# Landsat 5 geometry rectangle with coordinates in GEE result does not show correct AOI

Tags: google-earth-engine, land-surface-temperature, landsat-5

I am using this code to display LST https://code.earthengine.google.com/?accept_repo=users/sofiaermida/landsat_smw_lst.

I use the coordinates as the AOI -80.74, -5.08, -80.51, -5.26 but the result show a "cut" section. If I for example increase the size of the AOI by changing the coordinates, it still does not show the the correct images for my AOI. The problem only occurs when I work with Landsat 5 images; with Landsat 8 it works perfectly. Does anyone know what the problem is?

```js
// link to the code that computes the Landsat LST
var LandsatLST = require('users/sofiaermida/landsat_smw_lst:modules/Landsat_LST.js')


// select region of interest, date range, and landsat satellite

var geometry = ee.Geometry.Rectangle([-80.74, -5.08, -80.51, -5.26]);

var satellite = 'L5';

var date_start = '1990-01-01';

var date_end = '1990-01-30';

var use_ndvi = true;

// get landsat collection with added variables: NDVI, FVC, TPW, EM, LST

var LandsatColl = LandsatLST.collection(satellite, date_start, date_end, geometry, use_ndvi)
print(LandsatColl)

// select the first feature

var exImage = LandsatColl.first();

var cmap1 = ['blue', 'cyan', 'green', 'yellow', 'red'];

var cmap2 = ['F2F2F2','EFC2B3','ECB176','E9BD3A','E6E600','63C600','00A600']; 

Map.centerObject(geometry)

Map.addLayer(exImage.select('TPW'),{min:0.0, max:60.0, palette:cmap1},'TCWV')

Map.addLayer(exImage.select('TPWpos'),{min:0.0, max:9.0, palette:cmap1},'TCWVpos')

Map.addLayer(exImage.select('FVC'),{min:0.0, max:1.0, palette:cmap2}, 'FVC')

Map.addLayer(exImage.select('EM'),{min:0.9, max:1.0, palette:cmap1}, 'Emissivity')

Map.addLayer(exImage.select('B6'),{min:290, max:320, palette:cmap1}, 'TIR BT')

Map.addLayer(exImage.select('LST'),{min:290, max:320, palette:cmap1}, 'LST')

Map.addLayer(exImage.multiply(0.0000275).add(-0.2),{bands: ['SR_B4', 'SR_B3', 'SR_B2'], min:0, max:0.3}, 'RGB'
```